# Migrate from Azure DevOps 2020 on prem german to the english version

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

long time ago we made a bad decision to install the German version of the TFS Server. We upgraded to every new version of the tfs and now Azure DevOps Server 2020 but had no chance to change the language. Now we want to migrate to VSTS, but therefore we need an English version. As far as i know, MS supports only a migration of English DevOps Server to VSTS.
Finding this tool and reading the line "v9.0 - Added support for migration between other language versions of Azure DevOps. Developed for German -> English", we hope to have a solution for our problem.
Searching the docs, I could not find any hints how to do, even start with it.
Is there any documentation how to do it?

Regards Bernhard

Answer (score 0):

This is not documented but you need to look at the `LanguageMaps` and change the `Source` `LanguageMaps` to the words that your TFS uses for 'Area' or 'Iteration'.

```
 "Source": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/nkdagility-preview/",
    "Project": "myProjectName",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
```

In Spanish would be:

```
 "Source": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/nkdagility-preview/",
    "Project": "myProjectName",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Área",
      "IterationPath": "Iteración"
    }
  },
```